# How to call the construction of a pointer member variable in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

So I have a class called Player, with private pointer variables as such:

```
class Player
{
public:
    Player();

    void update();
    void draw();
private:
    InputCp* input;
    PhysicsCp* physics;
    GraphicsCp* graphics;
};
```

Each of InputCp, PhysicsCp and GraphicsCp have constructors which look like something like this:

```
PhysicsCp::PhysicsCp()
{
    // adjust values to change player physics
    normMaxSpeedX = 10;
    maxSprintSpeedX = 20;
    normAccel = 1;
    sprintAccel = 2;
    gravity = 2;
    initialJumpSpeed = 10;
}
```

How do I make it so that when a player constructor is called, so are the ones for the input, physics and graphics instances it has?

Comment: What does "instances it has" mean? `Player` doesn't have any instances, it just has a bunch of pointers.

Comment: It is strongly recommended to provide a destructor to a Player class if you want to use a raw pointers to dynamically allocated objects. Or use smart pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't use pointers :

Do :

```
class Player
{
public:
    Player();

    void update();
    void draw();
private:
    InputCp input;
    PhysicsCp physics;
    GraphicsCp graphics;
};
```

And your default constructors will be called for you.

---

**Note:**

- If you *really* need pointers (and the fact is that you rarely do), use smart pointers (`std:unique_ptr<>`,  for instance), to avoid the usual mess with pointer-related memory management.

Comment: The problem I have is that when I do that, it tells me that input, physics and graphics all have an incomplete type. (The Player.h file uses forward deceleration of the Cp classes.) Is there another way to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have to use forward declarations ? If you really need pointers, see my note, I can expan it if you need to

Comment: Um I'm not sure if I have to, I thought it was just good practice. doing #include might end me up with a circular dependency issue

Comment: It's good practice when you *need* it, i.e. to avoid circular includes. If you don't need it, just use `#includes`

Comment: yeah I thought as much. Well I could get away with using #include, so thank you

Answer (score 1):

They need to be created in the constructor

```
Player::Player()
{
    input = new InputCp;
    physics = new PhysicsCp;
    graphics = new GraphicsCp;
}
```

But make sure you don't leak them, so `delete` them in your destructor

```
Player::~Player() 
{
    delete input;
    delete physics;
    delete graphics;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this style, is that if PhysicsCp's or GraphicCp's constructors throw, you leak memory.  unique_ptr or any other safe pointer would prevent that.

Comment: Another problem is the usage of assignment rather than an initialization list.